# What does "All examples have been tested directly from the text, which is in machine-readable form" mean?

Tags: c

I am reading the classic book on C - `The C Programming Language
Book by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie`. The preface of the book says

> All examples have been tested directly from the text, which is in machine-readable form.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>(just a guess)</sup>

Probably that every code example has been indeed tested on a system with a C compiler, and [pretty-printed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prettyprint) in the book (perhaps using [`troff`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troff) or whatever [document formatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typesetting) was used by K&R) by some *automatic* tool (I don't know what tool was used by K&R. Today, you'll use e.g. [vgrind](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uvgrind.htm) or [pygments](http://pygments.org/) or LaTeX's [listings](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings) package, or some other pretty-printer). So there cannot be typos while converting C code to paper (e.g. as if the C code has been *manually* copied and typeset)

Comment: Yes — there are many examples of books containing code listings that are riddled with errors, especially older books that weren't typeset digitally, or were converted through some semi-manual process. K&R is letting the reader know that it isn't one of those.